# Issue with split one row to two parts in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to split one row into two parts, I am using UNION ALL.
I got the two parts but the result is not what I am looking for. 
The order is messed up.
I want the #3 and #4 row switch, and #7 and #8 row switch position.

[image]

Original row:

```
TIME, ORDER_NUM, THICKNESS, FORMULATION, SILO, SCREWOIL1_TEMP, SCREWOIL2_TEMP, MELTING_TEMP, FEEDER_LB, FEEDER_RPM, COMPOUND, RECLAIM_PERCENTAGE
```

Desired order should be:

First row:

```
TIME, ORDER_NUM, THICKNESS, FORMULATION, SILO, SCREWOIL1_TEMP, SCREWOIL2_TEMP
```

Second row:

```
TIME, MELTING_TEMP, FEEDER_LB, FEEDER_RPM, COMPOUND, RECLAIM_PERCENTAGE
```

Comment: You have it already. What's wrong with it?

Comment: When you post code, please post it in plain text so others can copy, paste and modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another another column to both `union`ed queries, turn the `union all` query to a subquery, and then use it to alternate the rows in the resultset:

```
select time, order_num, thickness, formulation, silo, screwoil1_temp
from (
    select time, order_num, thickness, formulation, silo, screwoil1_temp, 1 seq
    from ve28_table
    union all
    select  time, melting_temp, feeder_lb, feeder_rpm, compound, reclaim_percentage, 2
    from ve28table
) t
order by time, seq
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional sorting key, if you want to interleave the records.

```
select TIME, ORDER_NUM, THICKNESS, FORMULATION, SILO, SCREWOIL1_TEMP, SCREWOIL2_TEMP, MELTING_TEMP, FEEDER_LB, FEEDER_RPM, COMPOUND, RECLAIM_PERCENTAGE
from ((select TIME, ORDER_NUM, THICKNESS, FORMULATION, SILO, SCREWOIL1_TEMP, SCREWOIL2_TEMP, MELTING_TEMP, FEEDER_LB, FEEDER_RPM, COMPOUND, RECLAIM_PERCENTAGE,
              1 as priority
       from . . .
      ) union all
      (select TIME, MELTING_TEMP, FEEDER_LB, FEEDER_RPM, COMPOUND, RECLAIM_PERCENTAGE,
              2
       from . . .
      )
     ) t
order by time, priority;
```

Note that the column headers are all taken from the first query in the `union all`.  All rows in a result set have the same column names.

Comment: It shows error msg: 
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.